# Get column(s) sum value if matches with column(s) sum value in another column(s)

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
(
SELECT DISTINCT UniqueBatchNumber AS UBN, 
  count(ID) AS Count, 
  SUM(amount) AS Total, 
  InstrumentType AS IType 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE TransactionDate = '2012-10-01' 
GROUP BY UniqueBatchNumber, InstrumentType HAVING InstrumentType = 'c'
) 
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
  UniqueBatchNumber AS UBN, 
  count(ID) AS Count, 
  SUM(amount) AS Total, 
  InstrumentType AS IType 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE TransactionDate = '2012-10-01' 
GROUP BY UniqueBatchNumber, InstrumentType HAVING InstrumentType = 'd'
)
```

It returns this:

```
UBN  |  Count  | Total       | IType
8237 |  1      | 150689.43   | C
8238 |  26     | 42838.80    | C
8241 |  1      | 2410932.00  | C
8247 |  1      | 100.00      | C
8250 |  1      | 99297.05    | C
8256 |  1      | 1929.00     | C
8259 |  16     | 12623.86    | C
8269 |  1      | 7405022.45  | C
8238 |  1      | 346522.57   | D
8241 |  1      | 303.00      | D
8243 |  1      | 204066.05   | D
8246 |  1      | 100.00      | D
8247 |  1      | 99297.05    | D
8256 |  11     | 847.00      | D
8259 |  1      | 571888.90   | D
8279 |  5      | 3986.75     | D
```

I want to get the batch(UBN) values(or sum of values) of IType 'c' that match batch(UBN) values(sum of values) of IType d.

For example credit batch sum(**8247, 8250** = 99397.05) will match out corresponding debit batch sum(**8246, 8247**)

I have tried all combinations of things

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    UniqueBatchNumber AS UBN, 
    COUNT(ID) AS Count, 
    SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM 
    Transactions 
WHERE 
    TransactionDate = '2012-10-01' 
GROUP BY 
    UniqueBatchNumber
```

but just can't work it out yet, any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want only the ones where there are multiple entries with the same UBN but differing IType?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you give an example of the expected output?  It's not clear to me from your description.

Comment: It sounds like you want a set-intersection of the set of UBNs in `c`, and the set of UBNs in `d`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (Btw: the parentheses around the individual selects in a union are useless)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something along these lines get you close to what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    C.ubn AS ubn_C,
    D.ubn AS ubn_D,
    C.count AS Count_C,
    D.count AS Count_D,
    C.total AS MatchingTotal
FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        uniquebatchnumber AS ubn,
        Count(id) AS count,
        Sum(amount) AS total,
        Instrumenttype AS itype
    FROM            
        transactions
    WHERE           
        transactiondate = '2012-10-01'
        AND instrumenttype = 'c'
    GROUP BY        
        uniquebatchnumber,
        instrumenttype) AS C
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        uniquebatchnumber AS ubn,
        Count(id) AS count,
        Sum(amount) AS total,
        Instrumenttype AS itype
    FROM            
        transactions
    WHERE           
        transactiondate = '2012-10-01'
        AND instrumenttype = 'd'
    GROUP BY        
        uniquebatchnumber,
        instrumenttype) AS D
ON C.Total = D.Total
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. This is almost it. If only I could do something like ...ON SUM(C.Total) = SUM(D.Total). And how would I be able to get the unmatched batch numbers(ubns). Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure why you want to do something like ON SUM(c.total) = SUM(d.total). The query as written already matches on the sums of the amounts for each batch number (they are summed in the derived table queries).  Or do I not understand your requirement?

Comment: Thank you Joe...I realize that that is not feasible and even necessary because of the distinct UBN part. 
Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this query.
You have done 90% of work you only need to change little bit in your query.

```
SELECT
    A.UBN,
    SUM(ISNULL(A.Total,0)) Total
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT 
      UniqueBatchNumber AS UBN, 
      count(ID) AS Count, 
      SUM(amount) AS Total, 
      InstrumentType AS IType 
    FROM 
        Transactions 
    WHERE 
        TransactionDate = '2012-10-01' 
    GROUP BY 
        UniqueBatchNumber, 
        InstrumentType 
    HAVING 
        InstrumentType = 'c'

UNION 

    SELECT 
      DISTINCT 
      UniqueBatchNumber AS UBN, 
      count(ID) AS Count, 
      SUM(amount) AS Total, 
      InstrumentType AS IType 
    FROM 
        Transactions 
    WHERE 
        TransactionDate = '2012-10-01' 
    GROUP BY 
        UniqueBatchNumber, 
        InstrumentType 
    HAVING InstrumentType = 'd'
)
AS A
GROUP BY
    A.UBN
```

I suggest you to use  UNION instead of UNION ALL Bcoz Union is nit faster in terms of performance than UNION ALL.

This query is not tested.
Please reply if this query is giving any errors.

Comment: @Amazing Sey Reply if this query is not fit for you

Comment: Thank you for your response...tested it and looks very close to what i want...is it possible to include unmatched items too or I'll have to use another query.

Comment: which unmatched items do you want (specifically which column you want to add)

Comment: From both columns...Am testing further with a large dataset. Will feedback if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: No it is not neccessary to write another query for the output. It depends what type of output do you want.   1. Do you want sum for count also? 2. Lets say Total = 3 then do you want two rows with the same output?.   Please post expected output that you want.

Comment: Thank you Hardik for your answer and feedback. I appreciate the efforts.

Comment: It did but @Joe's answer fitted me the most. Thank you.